# Writing a function for a Generic Protocol in Swift with type aliases

Tags: generics, swift, functional-programming, type-constraints, type-alias

I'm using some code from the [basis](https://github.com/typelift/Basis) library and trying to write a generic function for a vector. This is my protocol,

```
//Inherits from Functor in the basis library
public protocol Vector: Functor {
    typealias VB = FB
    typealias C
    typealias VC = K1<C>

    class func foldl(B) -> ((A, B) -> B) -> Self -> B
    class func zipWith((A, B) -> C) -> Self -> VB -> VC
}
```

and I have a concrete implementation of the functions with a Vector2.

I'd like to define several generic functions since the protocol has fmap, foldl and zipWith. However, I just can't seem to write something which compiles like this,

```
//This is basically just an identity
func trailFunction<A, V: Vector where V.A == A, V.B == A, V.FB == V>(v: V) -> V {
    let f = V.fmap({$0})
    return f(v)

}

//Fails with B is not identical to Int error
func testFunction(v: Vector2<Int>) -> Vector2<Int> {
    return trailFunction(v)
}
```

What am I doing wrong?